# SVN dump file compatibility with higher version (eg. 1.14.x)

Tags: svn, compatibility, dump

I have SVN dump file created with 'svnadmin dump' command in SVN version 1.10.x. and Would like to store this data to some data-storage server location and want to retire/decommission the current old SVN server since we are not using SVN anymore.

If I need this SVN code sometime in future and want to re-dump/load it with higher version of Subversion installed, eg - 1.13.x or 1.14.x or xyz version of svn, will that repo dump file or repo zip file will be compatible and works with newer version ?

Tried dumping the repo and re-load the dumped repo in same version - works fine.

Comment: Should be possible. I can't look into the future. In the past, Subversion has always maintained good compatibility with previous versions. To be safe, you might just put your current Subversion installer next to the dump. I don't think you'll need it but it might buy you ease of mind.

Comment: Another thought, as Subversion version 1.14 is readily available, why don't you just test it yourself?

Comment: @Friedrich - Thanks for the comment and testing tips.